# How to print 5 first elements from an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So Im having some trouble coming up with a idea to make it work I´ve at it for the past 4 hours and still cant put it to work I returned to where I start to make things simple to understand.
Here´s the deal I have 2 menus on the first one I print all of the arrayList like it is supposed but one the second menu i can only print the first five products does anyone has a solution?
heres the code:

```
package projeto;
import java.util.*;



public class GestorDeCartoes {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //inicializa a lista de clientes e a de produtos
        ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Produto> listaProdutos = new ArrayList<>();
        long id = 2021129038;
        int pos = 1;
        int menu, menuCompra;

        do {
            System.out.println("\nEscolha a opção:\n1-Inserir Clientes\n2-Listar Clientes\n3-Inserir Produtos\n4-Listar Produtos\n5-Menu de Compra\n6-Sair");
            menu = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            switch (menu)
            {
                case (1):
                    System.out.println("Insira os dados do cliente:");
                    String inputCliente = scanner.nextLine();
                    String[] dadosCliente = inputCliente.split(",");
                    String nome = dadosCliente[0];
                    int idade = Integer.parseInt(dadosCliente[1]);
                    double pontos = Double.parseDouble(dadosCliente[2]);

                    //verifica se o nome introduzido é numerico
                    if(nome.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                        System.out.println("Dados inválidos");
                        break;
                    }

                    //verifica de a idade e os pontos introduzidos sao positivos
                    if ((idade < 0) || (pontos < 0)){
                        System.out.println("Dados inválidos");
                        break;
                    }

                    //cria o cliente, o cartao, adiciona a lista de clientes e incrementa o id
                    Cartao cartao = new Cartao(id, pontos);
                    Cliente cliente = new Cliente( pos , id, nome , idade , cartao );
                    listaClientes.add(cliente);
                    id++;
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case (2):
                    //lista os Clientes
                    for (Cliente ClienteIterador : listaClientes) {
                        System.out.println(ClienteIterador.toString());
                    }
                    break;
                case (3):
                    System.out.println("Insira os dados do produto:");
                    //le a linha a ser introduzida
                    String inputProduto = scanner.nextLine();
                    //separa a linha lida pelas virgulas num vetor
                    String[] dadosProduto = inputProduto.split(",");
                    //introduz os dados lidos para o vetor nas variaveis
                    int custo = Integer.parseInt(dadosProduto[1]);
                    String nomeProduto = dadosProduto[0];

                    //verifica se o nome introduzido é numerico
                    if(nomeProduto.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                        System.out.println("Dados inválidos");
                        break; 
                    }

                    //verifica se o custo introduzido é positivo
                    if (custo < 0){
                        System.out.println("Dados inválidos");
                        break;
                    }
                    //cria o produto e adiciona a lista
                    Produto produto = new Produto( id , custo , nomeProduto );
                    listaProdutos.add(produto);
                    id++;
                    break;
                case (4):
                    //lista os produtos
                    for (Produto produtoIterador : listaProdutos) {
                        System.out.println(produtoIterador.toString());

                    }
                    break;
                case (5):
                    System.out.println("\nMENU DE COMPRA\n");

                    do {
                        System.out.println("1-Ver a Lista de Produtos\n2-Comprar Produto\n3-Consultar o Saldo\n4-Sair\n5-Voltar\nEscolha a opção:");
                        menuCompra = scanner.nextInt();
                        switch (menuCompra) {
                            case (1):
                                //lista os produtos
                                for (Produto produtoIterador : listaProdutos) {
                                    System.out.println(produtoIterador.toString());
                                }
                                break;
                            case (2):
                                System.out.println("Introduza o nome do produto que quer comprar\n");
                                String compraProdutoString = scanner.next();

                                //verifica se o nome introduzido é numerico
                                if(compraProdutoString.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                                    System.out.println("Dados inválidos");
                                    break;
                                }
                                //filtra a lista de produtos pelo produto com o nome igual ao que queremos comprar
                                Produto produtoAComprar = null;
                                for (Produto compraProduto : listaProdutos) {
                                    if (compraProduto.obterNome().equals(compraProdutoString)) {
                                        produtoAComprar = compraProduto;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (produtoAComprar == null) {
                                    System.out.println("Produto inválido");
                                    break;
                                }
                                System.out.println("Introduza o nome do cliente:\n");
                                String compraClienteString = scanner.next();

                                //verifica se o nome introduzido é numerico
                                if(compraClienteString.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                                    System.out.println("Dados inválidos");
                                    break;
                                }
                                //filtra a lista de clientes pelo cliente com o nome igual ao que queremos utilizar
                                for (Cliente compraCliente : listaClientes) {
                                    if (compraCliente.obterNome().equals(compraClienteString)) {
                                        compraCliente.comprar(produtoAComprar);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }
                                break;
                            case (3):
                                //mostra o saldo do cliente
                                System.out.print("Introduza o nome do cliente:");
                                String ConsultaSaldoString = scanner.next();
                                for (Cliente compraCliente : listaClientes) {
                                    if (compraCliente.obterNome().equals(ConsultaSaldoString)) {
                                        compraCliente.mostrarSaldo();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }
                                break;

                            case (4): 
                                //fecha o scanner e sai do programa
                                System.out.println("Volte Sempre");
                                scanner.close();
                                return;
                            case(5):
                                break;
                            }
                            
                    } while (menuCompra!= 5);
                    break;                            
                case (6):
                    //fecha o scanner e sai do programa
                    System.out.println("Volte Sempre");
                    scanner.close();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Escolha um numero entre 1 e 5");
                    break;
            }
        } while (menu != 6);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you loop from 0 to 4, `.get()` the corresponding element from the list (the method takes a parameter of type `int` so you can use the current iteration of the loop there), and print it? What specific problem are you having with implementing this?

Comment: That’s a lot of code, and I can’t readily spot which lines are relevant. Please learn to create a [mre].

Comment: look at case(1) on MenuCompra thats where i am having trouble